# visual studio code enable debug continue

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am working with Angular CLI (started from zero from here https://cli.angular.io/)

and VS Code. I am trying to debug my code. The debug session is running but if I want to continue then I am getting following info:

> Command 'Debug: Continue' is not enabled in the current context.

This is my configuration for launching:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out/chrome"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I enable it within VS Code or how can I debug it?